# JSON.NET Classifying JsonReaderException's to their specific error

Tags: exception, json.net

I'm using the Newtonsoft json.NET parser for JSON parsing. In my deserialization, I have the following code so that errors when converting from String to Int will not force me to throw away the entire object:

```
var param2 = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Error = delegate(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
};
bcontent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BContent>(json, param2);
```

I do not have control of the input data and the parsing errors are very common so I need to be versatile enough to handle them. Unfortunately, marking all errors as handled causes the deserialization to not terminate when it runs into a different error in a constrained environment.

What I want to do is to mark the errors as handled when they are of a type with a similar message as:

```
Could not convert string to integer....
```

But not when they are something different, such as this error which causes the hang:

```
Unterminated string. Expected delimiter...
```

What I can do is something like this:

```
Error = delegate(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ErrorContext.Error.Message.Contains("convert string to integer"))
        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
}
```

But it seems like there's no other way to determine a more specific error than `JsonReaderException`. Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a better workaround than a `String.Contains()`?